# Mongoose document has no method "save" -- but also, it does

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When iterating over a set of documents returned by `Model.find()`, I pass each resulting document into another function that eventually calls the `save()` method. But I get this error:

```
[TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'save']
```

I've confirmed that the object in question is a Mongoose document. In fact -- and this is what really has me baffled...

```
console.log(order.save); // { [Function] numAsyncPres: 0 }
order.save(); // [TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'save']
```

I can't even understand how that's possible, for it to exist until I call it...

I'll provide more code for context if needed, but I'm crossing my fingers that this is some known oddness / stupid oversight on my part that someone will immediately be able to recognize.

Edit: On reviewing the error stack, I see that it *is* calling save. Otherwise, I'd be seeing an entirely different error message. Rather, the save method is failing to locate an internal save method. Here's the stack:

```
at C:\dev\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1272:13
at Array.forEach (native)
at model.pre.err.stack (C:\dev\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1254:12)
at model._next (C:\dev\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\hooks\hooks.js:50:30)
at model.proto.(anonymous function) [as save] (C:\dev\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\hooks\hooks.js:96:20)
at fixNoPriceItem (C:\dev\unimatrix\node_modules\cathy.js:202:10)
at Array.forEach (native)
at CallManager.callback (C:\dev\unimatrix\node_modules\cathy.js:181:18)
at Object.tracker.complete (C:\dev\unimatrix\node_modules\mowse\node_modules\constructors\Call-Manager.js:80:8)
at continueHandling (C:\dev\unimatrix\node_modules\mowse\node_modules\constructors\Call-Manager.js:138:14)
```

The function which actually calls `order.save` is `fixNoPriceItem`, the sixth one down.

The only alterations made to the document before save are the following:

```
order.items[targetIndex] = itemData; // items is an arr
order.markModified('items');
```

I suspect it's related to how I'm setting the subdocument...

Comment: I solved my problem by iterating over itemData's properties and assigning each to the existing item at that index, rather than actually replacing it. But I'm not adding that as an answer because I still don't know why the above fails. I tried using the `set` method and still got an error (a different one, though, about `id` not being a method...).

Comment: Please provide further contextual code, like where you are passing the data and when you are calling the save funciton